# How can I stop Microsoft Word (for Mac) from printing double sided by default?

Tags: ms-office, printing

My MS Word (2016) for Mac suddenly started printing every document double-sided by default - which I do not want ;)

Essentially, when I choose Print, it is selected by default on "Long-Edge binding" in the "Two-sided" option.
**File** > **Print** > **Copies & Pages** > **Layout** > **Two-sided** > **Long-Edge binding**

Every time, I have to manually turn it off to get basic, single-page printing.

The printer settings (Canon TS6161) seem fine, and it does that nowhere else - pdf, Word for Windows, etc. Only my Word for Mac.

Any idea how to change it or reset the default printing settings for Word?

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Word for Mac Print window]

Answer (score 1):

Can you get to a sheet similar to this?  All you need to be able to find is the duplex setting & the Preset drop-menu - it doesn't need to look identical to this.
<sub>Drop menu intentionally offset for legibility.</sub>

[image]

If so you can disable duplex, then Save current settings as Preset.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. More specifically - sharing this for others who might have the same issue - I needed to revert to "default settings", since for some reason the B&W setting has duplex by default. (PS: upvoted your answer, but since my reputation is not high enough yet, it doesn't show).